# Issues when freezing wx.Grid columns with FreezeTo: bad cell position in grid, and HOME keyboard key behavior

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, mouseover, keyboard-events

**Context**

I have put in place column freezing in a `wx.grid.Grid`, using `FreezeTo` method.

```
    def __init__(self, parent):
        # relevant lines
        self.grid = wx.grid.Grid(self.sbox_grid, size=(1000, 800))
        self.grid.CreateGrid(self.row_number, self.col_number)
        self.grid.FreezeTo(0, self.frozen_column_number)
```

The freezing by itself works well, as soon as I keep the standard label renderer (*).
The first few columns I have frozen always stay visible, and moving the horizontal scrollbar by hand is also ok.

(*) I was initially using the `GridWithLabelRenderersMixin` of `wx.lib.mixins.gridlabelrenderer`, but it totally breaks consistency between column label width and column width. Anyway I can deal with the standard renderer, so it is not really a problem.

I faced several issues, now all solved and detailed below.

**Capture the cell position for frozen columns: cells or labels (SOLVED)**

For cells, the window can be captured with `GetFrozenColGridWindow`.

So mouseover can be done simply with:

```
    if widget == self.grid.GetFrozenColGridWindow():
        (x, y) = self.grid.CalcUnscrolledPosition(event.GetX(), event.GetY())
        row = self.grid.YToRow(y)
        col = self.grid.XToCol(x)
        # do whatever your want with row, col
```

For labels, the window exists but is NOT accessible with a method.
With a `GetChildren` on the grid, I have found that it is the last of the list (corresponding to the latest defined).

So it is not very reliable, but a relatively good placeholder for the missing `GetGridFrozenColLabelWindow` method.

```
    wlist = self.grid.GetChildren()
    frozen_col_label_window = wlist[-1]
    if widget == frozen_col_label_window:
        x = event.GetX()
        y = event.GetY()
        col = self.grid.XToCol(x, y)
        # do stuff with col
```

**Mouse position from non-frozen columns (labels or cells) is shifted (SOLVED)**

The effective position for non-frozen columns labels or cells is shifted from the total width of all the frozen columns.

This one is easily handled by a shift in position, computed before calls to `YToRow` or `XToCol` methods.

The following code shows the position corrections:

```
class Report(wx.Panel):

    def _freeze_x_shit(self):
        """Returns the horizontal position offset induced by columns freeze"""
        offset = 0
        for col in range(self.frozen_column_number):
            offset += self.grid.GetColSize(col)
        return offset

    def on_mouse_over(self, event):
        widget = event.GetEventObject()
        
        # grid header
        if widget == self.grid.GetGridColLabelWindow():
            x = event.GetX()
            y = event.GetY()
            x += self._freeze_x_shit()  # <-- position correction here
            col = self.grid.XToCol(x, y)
            # do whatever grid processing using col value

        # grid cells
        elif widget == self.grid.GetGridWindow():
            (x, y) = self.grid.CalcUnscrolledPosition(event.GetX(), event.GetY())
            x += self._freeze_x_shit()  # <-- and also here
            row = self.grid.YToRow(y)
            col = self.grid.XToCol(x)
            # do whatever grid cell processing using row and col values

        event.Skip()
```

**HOME keyboard key not working as intended (SOLVED)**

I generally use the `HOME` key to immediately go at the utmost left of the grid, and the `END` key to go far right. This is the normal behavior with a non-frozen grid.

The `END` key does its jobs, but not the `HOME` key.

When pushing `HOME` on any grid cell, I got two effects:

- the selected cell becomes the first column: this is OK
- but the scrollbar position is not changed at all: I would expect the scroll position to be fully left

I have corrected it by a simple remapping using `EVT_KEY_DOWN` event:

```
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.grid.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.on_key_event)

        def on_key_event(self, event):
            """Remap the HOME key so it scrolls the grid to the left, as it did without the frozen columns

            :param event: wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN event on the grid
            :return:
            """
            key_code = event.GetKeyCode()
            if key_code == wx.WXK_HOME:
                self.grid.Scroll(0, -1)

            event.Skip()
```

Comment: I have solved my first issue: Capture the cell position for frozen columns: cells or labels. I have edited my post with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

my 3 issues concerning column Freeze in a grid are now solved. I have edited my initial post with my solutions.